# Inconveniente con instalación de Drivers parea USB LATERALES en equipo Compaq 18-4121la

Tags: windows, windows10, controller

Cordial saludo, necesito preguntarles acerca del siguiente inconveniente que tengo referente a los drivers de USB lateral de un computador Compaq 18-4121la agradezco anticipadamente su ayuda.

En la opción de administrador de dispositivos,  me aparece que los dos puestos USB tiene  error:
El último dispositivo USB que conectó a este equipo no funciono correctamente, y Windows no lo reconoció.
Recomendación
Intenta volver a conectar el dispositivo. Si Windows aún no lo reconoce, probablemente el dispositivo no esté funcionando correctamente.

Ya he aplicado actualizando controladores, descargándolos, Habilitando y deshabilitando el dispositivo y no he tenido éxito , no me lo sigue reconociendo
Gracias!.

Comment: Buen día, desde el administrador de dispositivos primero intenta escanear los cambios de `hardware` (No sé como diga en español). Si eso no funciona intenta encontrar el puerto USB en la lista y dale click derecho, desinstala el drive y luego presiona nuevamente el botón de escanear.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias, esto es lo que estoy realizando: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k6GgNjJ-gck